# How to include \n, \t, \r and similar items to json.loads?

Tags: python, json

I want to include \n not as newline but as a string literal in json.loads

for example, json.loads('"hello\n"')

how do i handle the \?

Answer (score 2):

`\n` is the [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) for line feed. Use the `\\` escape sequence: `json.loads('"hello\\n"')`

Alternatively, use a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), which treats a backslash as a literal character: `json.loads(r'"hello\n"')`